# How do I load objects to the current environment from a function in R?

Tags: r

Instead of doing

```
a <- loadBigObject("a")
b <- loadBigObject("b")
```

I'd like to call a function like

```
loadBigObjects(list("a","b"))
```

And be able to access the `a` and `b` objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not clear what `loadBigObjects()` does or where it will look for `a` and `b`. How does it load the objects from file or sourcing code?

There are lots of options in general:

- `sys.source()` allows an R file to be sourced to a given environment
- `load()` which will load an `.Rdata` file to a given environment
- `assign()` in combination with any object created by `loadBigObjects()` or a call to `readRDS()` can also load an object to a given environment.

From within your function, you'll want to specify the environment in which to load objects as the Global Environment by using `globalenv()`. If you don't do that then the object will only exist in the evaluation frame of the running `loadBigObjects()`. E.g.

```
loadBigObjects <- function(list) {
    lapply(list, function(x) assign(x, readRDS(x), envir = globalenv()))
}
```

(as per your comment to @GSee's Answer, and assuming the `list("a","b")` is sufficient information for `readRDS()` to locate and open the object.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect, but I think it's globalenv(), not global.env()

Comment: @GavinSimpson Do you mean `loadBigObjects <- function(list) {`?

Comment: Uggh not my night for typos. Yes, well spotted.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing anything about what `loadBigObject` is or does, you can use `lapply` to apply a function to a list of objects

```
lapply(list("a", "b"), loadBigObject)
```

If you provided the code for `loadBigObject` or at least describe what it is supposed to do, a better `loadBigObjects` function could probably be written.

Answer (score 2):

The `assign` function can be used to define a variable in an environment other than the current one.

```
loadBigObjects <- function(lst) {
  lapply(lst, function(l) {
    assign(l, loadBigObject(l), envir=globalenv())
  }
  lst
}
```

(Not that this is necessarily a good idea.)